# TensorFlow on multiple GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, multiple-gpu

Recently, I try to learn how to use Tensorflow on multiple GPU by reading the official tutorial. However, there is something that I am confused about. The following code is part of the official tutorial, which calculates the loss on single GPU.

```
def tower_loss(scope, images, labels):

  # Build inference Graph.
  logits = cifar10.inference(images)

  # Build the portion of the Graph calculating the losses. Note that we will
  # assemble the total_loss using a custom function below.
  _ = cifar10.loss(logits, labels)

  # Assemble all of the losses for the current tower only.
  losses = tf.get_collection('losses', scope)

  # Calculate the total loss for the current tower.
  total_loss = tf.add_n(losses, name='total_loss')

  # Attach a scalar summary to all individual losses and the total loss; do the
  # same for the averaged version of the losses.
  for l in losses + [total_loss]:
    # Remove 'tower_[0-9]/' from the name in case this is a multi-GPU training
    # session. This helps the clarity of presentation on tensorboard.
    loss_name = re.sub('%s_[0-9]*/' % cifar10.TOWER_NAME, '', l.op.name)
    tf.summary.scalar(loss_name, l)

  return total_loss
```

The training process is as the following.

```
def train():
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # Create a variable to count the number of train() calls. This equals the
    # number of batches processed * FLAGS.num_gpus.
global_step = tf.get_variable(
    'global_step', [],
    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)

# Calculate the learning rate schedule.
num_batches_per_epoch = (cifar10.NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN /
                         FLAGS.batch_size / FLAGS.num_gpus)
decay_steps = int(num_batches_per_epoch * cifar10.NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY)

# Decay the learning rate exponentially based on the number of steps.
lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(cifar10.INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE,
                                global_step,
                                decay_steps,
                                cifar10.LEARNING_RATE_DECAY_FACTOR,
                                staircase=True)

# Create an optimizer that performs gradient descent.
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)

# Get images and labels for CIFAR-10.
images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()
batch_queue = tf.contrib.slim.prefetch_queue.prefetch_queue(
      [images, labels], capacity=2 * FLAGS.num_gpus)
# Calculate the gradients for each model tower.
tower_grads = []
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
  for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
    with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
      with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (cifar10.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
        # Dequeues one batch for the GPU
        image_batch, label_batch = batch_queue.dequeue()
        # Calculate the loss for one tower of the CIFAR model. This function
        # constructs the entire CIFAR model but shares the variables across
        # all towers.
        loss = tower_loss(scope, image_batch, label_batch)

        # Reuse variables for the next tower.
        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

        # Retain the summaries from the final tower.
        summaries = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES, scope)
```

However, I am confused about the for loop about 'for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus)'. It seems that I have to get a new batch image from batch_queue and calculate every gradient. I think this process is serialized instead of parallel. If there anything wrong with my own understanding? By the way, I can also use the iterator to feed image to my model rather than the dequeue right?

Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common misconception with Tensorflow's coding model.
What you are showing here is the computation graph's *construction*, NOT the actual execution.

The block:

```
for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
    with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
      with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (cifar10.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
        # Dequeues one batch for the GPU
        image_batch, label_batch = batch_queue.dequeue()
        # Calculate the loss for one tower of the CIFAR model. This function
        # constructs the entire CIFAR model but shares the variables across
        # all towers.
        loss = tower_loss(scope, image_batch, label_batch)
```

translates to:

```
For each GPU device (`for i in range..` & `with device...`):
    - build operations needed to dequeue a batch
    - build operations needed to run the batch through the network and compute the loss
```

Note how via `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()` you're telling the graph that the variables used for the graph GPU must be shared among all (i.e., all graphs on the multiple devices "reuse" the same variables).

None of this actually runs the network once (note how there is no `sess.run()`): you're just giving instructions on how data must flow.

Then, when you'll start the actual training (I guess you missed that piece of the code when copying it here) each GPU will pull its own batch and produce the per-tower loss. I guess these losses are averaged somewhere in the subsequent code and the average is the loss passed to the optimizer.

Up until the point where the tower losses are averaged together, everything is independent from the other devices, so getting the batch and computing the loss can be done in parallel. Then the gradients and parameter update is done only once, variables are updated and the cycle repeats.

So, to answer your question, **no**, per-batch loss computation is not serialized, but since this is synchronous distributed computation you need to collect all losses from all GPUs before being allowed to continue with gradients computation and parameters update, so you still have *some* part of the graph that cannot be independent.

Comment: Well, thank you for your patient explanation and I get the point that you mentioned above. Actually, after the building of the graph, the CPU will collect the gradients from each GPU and average them in order to update the variables. By the way, in this instance, the author uses the 'batch_queue_dequeue()' to feed a new batch for each GPU. However, I think I can just create an iterator directly in my graph, right?